# Using Jmagick into an Android project

Tags: android, jmagick

I would use [Jmagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html) into an Android Project.
Is it possible? 
I have to recompile source code with ndk?
Are there some tutorial/guide for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an android project with a compile version of ImageMagick:
[Android-ImageMagick](https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick)